# A question on Perron vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-matrices

Let $A ∈ M_n$ be positive and let $x = [x_i ]$ be the Perron vector of $A$.

Suppose $\rho (A) = \mathop {\min }\limits_i \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{a_{ij}}}  $ or $\rho (A) = \mathop {\max }\limits_i \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{a_{ij}}} $

Why does $x_1 = · · · = x_n$?

(Note :  $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$).

Comment: Is $A$ stochastic? Is it irreducible?

Comment: @Marcel - No.                                            .

Comment: Is it not stochastic? Is it not irreducible? Or you don't know? What is the definition of $\rho(A)$? How do you know that $x_1=...=x_n$? You must give more information when you ask a question.

Comment: @Marcel - I edited this post.Can we say $A$ stochastic?

Comment: How do you know the largest eigenvector is not degenerate?

Comment: @Marcel - I don't understand, Please more guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the eigenvector equation $Ax=\lambda x$ for the largest eigenvalue. This means $$\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}x_j=\lambda x_i$$ for every $i$. If we also know that $$\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}=\lambda,$$ then $x_1=\cdots=x_N$ is obviously a solution.

These are $N$ linear equations with $N$ unknowns, so if the equations are linearly independent, the system has a single solution and this is the end. If they are not L.I., you could have other solutions and then $\lambda$ would be degenerate.

Maybe you should look up the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

EDIT.

The above part of the answer assumes $A$ is stochastic, i.e. every row sum is equal to $\lambda$. But this can be proved from the condition $\lambda={\rm max}\sum_{j}a_{ij}$, as follows.

Suppose the first row has the largest sum, $\sum_{j}a_{1j}=\lambda$ and suppose $x_1=1$ so $\sum_{j}a_{1j}x_j=\lambda$ as well.

If $x$ is constant, stochasticity of $A$ is obvious. So assume $x$ is not constant. It is not possible for $x_i<1$ for all $i>2$ or this would contradict the above. So some $x_i$ must be larger than $1$. Suppose the largest $x_i$ is $x_2$.

Then $\sum_{j}a_{2j}x_j=\lambda x_2.$ On the other hand, $\sum_{j}a_{2j}x_j<(\sum_{j}a_{2j}) x_2.$ It follows that $\lambda<\sum_{j}a_{2j}$.

But this contradicts the assumption that the first row had the largest sum.

Therefore, all rows must have the same sum.

Comment: What means 'degenerate'?

Comment: Can we deduce that every row sum of $A$ is equal to $ρ(A)$?

Comment: Yes, see the edited answer. "degenerate" means two eigenvalues are equal.